# Counter Clockwise Circular Motion Expression in After Effects

Tags: position, expression, after-effects

Hope I'm posting this in the right section, apologys if not.

I have a expression that I use on an objects position in After Effects:

```
radius = 35;
startAngle = degreesToRadians(180);
T = 22;
angularSpeed = 2 * 3.1415926 / T;
xt =1082 + radius * Math.cos(angularSpeed * time + startAngle); 
yt = 536 + radius * Math.sin(angularSpeed * time + startAngle);
[xt, yt]
```

My questions, is how do I make it go counter clockwise as oppsoed to cloackwise?

Any help appreciated,

Ian

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do ? Why T=22 ? Wbat is 1082 and 536 ?

Comment: change angularSpeed to -angularSpeed